# How to convert a list of lists into a polars dataframe with a column of type list[struct[n]]?

Tags: dataframe, list, struct, tuples, python-polars

I have a list of lists. Each of the individual list may be of different lengths. Each element of the list is tuple.

```
list1 = [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
list2 = [("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("e", 5)]
```

I want to combine all of them in a single polars dataframe column that is of type list[struct[2]].

On printing the dataframe I should get to see:

```
    column_name

    list[struct[2]]

    [{"a",1}, {"b",2}]
    [{"c",3}, {"d",4}, {"e",5}]
```

All I have managed to do is get a column of struct[2] using the code below

```
    list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
    list2 = [1, 2, 3]

    df = pl.DataFrame({
        "col1": list1,
        "col2": list2
    })

    print (df)
    dfs = df.select(pl.struct(pl.all()).alias("my_struct"))
    print(dfs)
```

But this is nowhere near what I want to achieve

SOLVED:
I solved this using the following code. Looks like in polars struct has the same meaning as a dict in ordinary python.

```
list1 = [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
list2 = [("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("e", 5)]
list_of_lists = [list1, list2]
lofl_as_structs = [[dict(f1=pair[0], f2=pair[1]) for pair in lst] for lst in list_of_lists]
df = pl.DataFrame({"column_name": lofl_as_structs})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ column_name                 │
│ ---                         │
│ list[struct[2]]             │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"a",1}, {"b",2}]          │
│ [{"c",3}, {"d",4}, {"e",5}] │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

Additional Issue:

I would like to be able to do the above slightly differently by specifying a schema as follows:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(lofl_as_structs,schema={'column_name': pl.List(pl.Struct([pl.Field('f1', pl.Utf8), pl.Field('f2', pl.Int64)]))})
```

This gives the error:

```
    raise ShapeError("the row data does not match the number of columns")
polars.exceptions.ShapeError: the row data does not match the number of columns
```

Any clues on what to change in the schema to get rid of this error.

Comment: what should the keys of your structs be?

Comment: The keys could be anything. They are not important as you can see from my solution above. But now I would like to be able to specify the schema directly and make this work. Thanks!!

Comment: You'd need another `[]` in order for it to be parsed as a single column, e.g. `pl.DataFrame([lofl_as_structs], ...)`

Answer (score 3):

Each column in Polars has a schema ("type").

If we take `{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}` as an example:

```py
df = pl.select(pl.concat_list(pl.struct(a=1), pl.struct(b=2)))
```

```py
shape: (1, 1)
┌──────────────────────┐
│ a                    │
│ ---                  │
│ list[struct[2]]      │
╞══════════════════════╡
│ [{1,null}, {null,2}] │ # [{"a": 1, b: None}, {"a": None: b: 2}]
└──────────────────────┘
```

Polars determines the schema to be: `[ {"a": int, "b": int } ]`

```
>>> df.schema
OrderedDict([('a', List(Struct([Field('a', Int32), Field('b', Int32)])))])
```

Which basically means: every struct in a column must have the same field names. (keys)

If we take your starting lists: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are all keys.

```py
list1 = [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
list2 = [("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("e", 5)]
```

```py
>>> dict(list1)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> dict(list2)
{'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

If you want the struct you've shown, you are essentially saying you want this:

```
list1 = [{"key": "a", "value": 1}, {"key": "b", "value": 2}]
list2 = [{"key": "c", "value": 3}, {"key": "d", "value": 4}, {"key": "e", "value": 5}]
```

i.e. your starting *keys* must become actual *values*.

Comment: No, "a", "b", etc. are as much values as 1, 2, etc. But since I have solved the problem, I would appreciate any help with solving the new issue of directly specifying the schema for this. Thanks!!

Comment: @vinnewbie Yes, I understand that you want to use them as "values", but if you look at the output of `dict(list1)` they end up becoming "keys" in the resulting dict. That was the point I was trying to get across.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want your keys to be `'0', '1', ...`, you could do:

```py
pl.Series(
    [[{str(i): val for i, val in enumerate(j)} for j in lst] for lst in [list1, list2]]
)
```

This gives

```py
Out[26]:
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [list[struct[2]]]
[
        [{"a",1}, {"b",2}]
        [{"c",3}, {"d",4}, {"e",5}]
]
```